# Can't see breakpoint values anymore in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I need to type "System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine(Parameter)" to see the value of that parameter where I have set a breakpoint. How come I can't see the value anymore when I hover my mouse over it?

Comment: Have you accidentally set your config to Release?

Comment: The interface usually tells you the reason - for example, the value might have been optimized away. What does VS say?